# Nginx MP4 Seeking results to video error

Tags: video, nginx

When using `?start=secs` with `nginx mp4`, video doesn't play for about 8 seconds although the audio keeps playing.

example:

```
http ://server/video.mp4 >>> plays correctly

http ://server/video.mp4?end=60 >>> plays correctly

http ://server/video.mp4?start=120 >>> starts audio playing with static image (video not working) for about 7-8 seconds.
```

I tried many MP4 files, all of them show first 7-8 seconds without video.
All files have moov atom at beginning.

Seems like `nginx` doesn't get the starting video frame correctly, any advice?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably not a key frame at that point in time. Most encoders use a long GOP for better compression. X264 defaults to 250. Try encoding with more key frames, or picking times just before key frames.

Comment: thanks for reply. is there a method/tool to get list of keframes with time seconds or bytes for an MP4 file?